# Grails 3 in Tomcat 6

Tags: deployment, war, tomcat6, grails-3.0.10

I am trying to deploy my grails app version 3 on a Tomcat 6 container and I am facing the following error when tomcat is trying to deploy the app:

```html
Jan 05, 2016 5:24:44 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(C:\Users\murruer\DEV\apache-tomcat-6.0.37\webapps\grailstomcat-0.1\WEB-INF\lib\tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
```

Is it possible to deploy a Grails 3 application into Tomcat 6??

Thank your.
Best Regards.

Answer (score 3):

If you read the official Grails Doc you can see this:

Note that by default Grails will **include an embeddable version of Tomcat inside the WAR file**, this can cause problems if you deploy to a different version of Tomcat. If you don't intend to use the embedded container then you should change the scope of the Tomcat dependencies to provided prior to deploying to your production container in **build.gradle**:

```
provided "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
```

**--Edit--**

Another problem deploying a Grails 3x war into a Tomcat 6 server is that it's not suported.

The official documentatiotion says:

Grails runs on any container that supports Servlet 3.0 and above and is known to work on the following specific container products:

- Tomcat 7
- GlassFish 3 or above
- Resin 4 or above
- JBoss 6 or above
- Jetty 8 or above
- Oracle Weblogic 12c or above
- IBM WebSphere 8.0 or above